# Angular2 Share data between components

Tags: angular, components

Hello i would like to share title between components. I have component app.component which declare title property and all another components are children. I have page-header.component which write title to html and dashboard.component which set title property and title dont show. Here is my code:

**app.component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

**page-header.component**

```
export class PageHeaderComponent extends AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
  }

}
```

**page-header.component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

**dashboard.component**

```
export class DashboardComponent extends AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.title = "Dashboard";
  }
}
```

For greater clarity i added image:
[image: Communication between components]

I would like to easy set title in any component (child of AppComponent) and title will be write to page header component

Comment: you can create a `common-component` and use it across the page by having the other components as child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are overcomplicating things you have two ways to share data in angular whether by using a service or by using the `@Input` decorator just like this

in the `page-header.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  `
})
export class PageHeaderComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

in the parent component of `page-header.component.ts` which is `app.component.ts` you do the following

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [title]="parentTitle"</app-child>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
 @Input() parentTitle: string;
}
```

and in the parent component of `app.component.ts` which is the `dashboard.component.ts` you do

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-parent-parent'
template : `
<app-parent [parentTitle] = "parentParentTitle"</app-parent>
`
})
  export class DashboardComponent {
 parentParentTitle = "Dashboard";     
 }
```

alternatively, you can create a service with a setter and getter methods and you inject it in the three components to set or get data between all of them.

Comment: But when I create child from AppComponent and in ngOninput i set this.parentTitle, dont change in page-header.component

Comment: your question is not that clear but can you try to set the `parentTitle` in the constructor of the `AppComponent` not in the `ngOnInit()` method

Comment: @bluray yes it's clear now, I have also updated my answer showing you how you can do it with a parent- child relation method but if you want to use the second method to create a service just let me know and I will write the full 3 components for you

Answer (score 2):

you can use ngRedux :

- run from you cmd

  ```
  npm install --save-dev ng2-redux redux
  ```
- at your app.module.ts add ngRedux at your constructor

  ```
  export class AppModule {
   constructor(ngRedux : NgRedux<IAppState>){
      ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
   }
  }
  ```
- create store.ts file and decleare ther all your share data

  ```
  export interface IAppState {
    globalData?: Data;
  }

  export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
    globalData: null
  };

  export function rootReducer(state: IAppState = INITIAL_STATE, action: Action): IAppState {
  ```

  switch (action.type) {
      case UPDATE_DATA:
        return Object.assign(state, state, (action));
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
- Create action.ts file

  ```
   export const UPDATE_DATA = 'UPDATE_DATA';

   export interface UpdateGlobalAction extends Action {
     globalData: Data;
   }
  ```
- at your components constructor inject ngRedux

  ```
   constructor(private ngRedux : NgRedux<IAppState>) {

   }

   //call to share data
   this.ngRedux.getState().globalData
  ```
- you can update you share data with

  ```
   this.ngRedux.dispatch({type : UPDATE_DATA, globalData : data} as UpdateGlobalAction);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Services is a good solution you can use it for example like this :

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MySecondSvc} from '../services/MySecondSvc';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{title}}'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "Angular 2 beta";
  constructor(private _secondSvc:MySecondSvc) { console.clear(); }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = this._secondSvc.getValue();
  }
}
```

MySecondSvc.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class MySecondSvc {
  title = "Hello";
  getValue() {
    return this.title;
  }
}
```

[live](http://plnkr.co/edit/uuNQk0r2bYdqnqp17DZE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this solution, I must inject MySecondSvc to all components. I would like only call this.title property.

Answer (score 0):

I was create simple example. My problem is app.component.html dont update property title.

```
extend class AppCoponent {
 title: string;
 constructor(){this.title = "App"}
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

DashboardComponent

```
  extend class DashboardComponent extend AppComponent{
     constructor(){
     this.title = "Dashboard";
    }
    }
```

In title is allways App instead of Dashboard