# Angular2/4: How to share property values across multiple components?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm a total beginner when it comes to Angular2/4, and I'm trying to make some sort of multi-step builder wizard. Right now it consists of a bunch of hardcoded transparent images on top of each other, which are shown depending on number conditions. When you click a button, a number value is assigned to a property, which triggers a  using *ngIf.

Each step is a Component, also using *ngIf to show depending on a numerical property value.

The first step is a choice of 3 different bike types, after which you choose a color.

How can I keep the property value from the bike component, so the image stays when I show the template from the color component?

First, the component with step buttons:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

public step : number = 1;

increment(){
this.step += 1;
}

decrement(){
this.step -= 1;
}
}
```

...and the HTML markup for that component:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

    <bike *ngIf="step == 1"></bike>
    <color *ngIf="step == 2"></color>
    <!-- <drivetrain *ngIf="step == 3"></drivetrain> -->
    <!-- <customize *ngIf="step == 4"></customize> -->
    <!-- <accessories *ngIf="step == 5"></accessories> -->
    <!-- <extras *ngIf="step == 6"></extras> -->

</div><br>

<button class="btn-success inline"(click)="decrement() ">PREV</button>
<button class="btn-success inline"(click)="increment() ">NEXT</button>
```

The following is step 2, in which the "bike" value is supposed to stay from the first step.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BikeComponent } from './bike.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'color',
template: `

<div style="width:700px; margin:auto;">

<div *ngIf="bike == 0">
<img src="/assets/images/drivetrain1.png" style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 0">
<img src="/assets/images/frameblack.png" style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 1">
<img src="/assets/images/framered.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 2">
<img src="/assets/images/frameblue.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 3">
<img src="/assets/images/framelgreen.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 4">
<img src="/assets/images/frameyellow.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 5">
<img src="/assets/images/framewhite.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 6">
<img src="/assets/images/frameorange.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 7">
<img src="/assets/images/framedgreen.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>

<div *ngIf="color == 8">
<img src="/assets/images/framegray.png"  style="position: fixed;">
</div>


<br>

<div class="buttons-color" style="text-align:middle;">
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" (click)="onClick(0)">BLACK</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger inline" (click)="onClick(1)">RED</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" (click)="onClick(2)">BLUE</button>
<button class="btn btn-success inline" (click)="onClick(3)">GREEN</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" (click)="onClick(4)">YELLOW</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" (click)="onClick(5)">WHITE</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" (click)="onClick(6)">ORANGE</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" (click)="onClick(7)">DARK G</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" (click)="onClick(8)">GRAY</button>
</div>

</div><br>

`,
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class ColorComponent {

bike = 0;
color = 0;


  onClick(colorValue) {
      this.color = colorValue;
  }

  }
```

I realize this is a beginners question, but I have been Googling and reading tutorials/stackoverflow for days. I have no clue how to do it. I also realize that my code is crap, and I would love a completely different way of doing it, if you know one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Share data between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175781/angular2-share-data-between-components)

Answer (score -1):

Ok so let me explain the kind of architecture you will be required to build.

first of all a components container that will hold all the steps like you did

```
<bike *ngIf="step == 1"></bike>
<color *ngIf="step == 2"></color>
<!-- <drivetrain *ngIf="step == 3"></drivetrain> -->
<!-- <customize *ngIf="step == 4"></customize> -->
<!-- <accessories *ngIf="step == 5"></accessories> -->
<!-- <extras *ngIf="step == 6"></extras> -->
```

Now what you want lets say is to save configuration of what the user have selected in each step.
bike type , color and so on.

each of those components lets say bike component , will emit data upon selection.

```
 export class BikeComponent {
 @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter();

 select(type){
   this.onSelect.emit(type);
 }
}
```

now in order to recieve the bike type on your top level component the one who renders all the steps you do as follows.

```
<bike *ngIf="step == 1" (onSelect)="bikeType = $event"></bike>
```

now if you want to pass the bikeType to other steps you need to create inputs in those components like follows.

```
export class ColorComponent {
 @Input() bikeType;
}
```

and inside html

```
<color *ngIf="step == 2" [bikeType]="bikeType"></color>
```

now you have shared information from step to step 2 and you can do this however you want and with what ever you want to share.

Comment: Pasting a link with no further explanation cant be considered an answer

Comment: this is a tutorial with code example. il give you an example code.

Comment: ok , tell what data would you like to share across different components?

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment, but I would like to share the number value of the "bike" property. Later on I would like to share the "color" property as well, but I assume that would be done in exactly the same way.

Now I get an error TS2304 Cannot find name "BikeService", even when I have made a bike.service.ts, and imported it into AppModule and put as a provider. This is weird.

Comment: ohhh. You don't need service then there is a better way to do it using best practices. I will show you an example code hopefully you will understand.

Comment: Hopefully you will be able to understand and implement